# Who might I have to defend my title against?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In Pokémon Sun/Moon, since you're the first Pokémon League champion, you're set to *defend* your title as Pokémon League Champion, rather than repeatedly taking the title from your rival or whoever the champion before you was. Unlike previous iterations in the series, who you fight in the championship match changes.

So far, after beating

> Professor Kukui,

I've had to defend my title against

> Hau and Molayne.

This leads me to believe that there are a vast number of challengers I could have to defend my title against. However, at least one captain is also a member of the Elite Four, so not all captains could be challengers. That said, is there a list of who all could potentially challenge me? I know Red and Blue are in this game, so could they challenge me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serebii has compiled a [challenger list](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/elitefour.shtml). They state that there are 10 potential challengers you will face, chosen at random. This is excluding the first time you beat the league which is fixed. According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_League_(Alola)/Title_Defense), the first title defense (second time in the league) is also a fixed challenger. And one challenger only appears on a certain day of the month.

Challenger names listed in spoiler below.

> Hau (First title defence/second time at the league)
>  Sophocles
>  Ryuki
>  Gladion
>  Molayne
>  Plumeria
>  Hapa
>  Faba  (Always appears on the first of the month)
>  Tristan
>  Kukui (First time in the league)

Comment: As far as I know, the first challenger (so, the second time you beat the league overall) is also fixed to be the first one on your list.

Comment: @scenia Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is random. I mostly get

> Molayne.

I dont think Red or Blue are challengers, sadly. They are just battle tree guys. They are really strong, though.

Comment: It's not random out of all characters in the game, it's random out of a specific list, which is given in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

Trust me, beat the elite 4 53 times then you'll be facing challengers from the other previous games. If you don't think its true check out the youtube videos then you'll have proof.

Comment: That doesn't tell me who, though.

Comment: Linking to some of these Youtube videos showing Elite 4 challengers from previous games would go a long way to validating your claim. As it stands, I'm more inclined to trust Serebii (as linked in the accepted answer) over you - Serebii have been a solid and reliable source of Pokemon gaming knowledge for a long time.