# I want to challenge the Elite Four again, but do I have to battle Professor Kukui again?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I ran away from Tapu Lele, and I heard that you can only catch it again after beating the Elite Four, but I don't want to battle Professor Kukui again.  Do I really have to fight him again?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to battle him again?

Comment: Battling him was quite hard for me

Answer (score 0):

As to whether you'll need to fight Professor Kukui *specifically*, you **might**:

*Yes*, you will need to beat the Pokemon League again in order to have another opportunity to catch Tapu Lele, as explained in [this article](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon-sun-moon/catch-the-tapu):

> If you KO the Tapu instead of catching it, you can get another chance by battling the Pokémon League again.

However, it's **not** guaranteed that you'll be fighting against Professor Kukui again. A full list of potential challengers is given in the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292439/who-might-i-have-to-defend-my-title-against).

---

In your case, a good idea would be to try to catch the remaining Tapu Pokemon *before* re-challenging the Pokemon League, though, since if you fail to catch any of the others, they will all be respawned once you beat the Pokemon League again.